# how are the intervals of histogram plot identified

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I was trying out a simple histogram

```
hist(c(-2,-1,0,1,2))
```

the histogram has frequency equal to 2 for -2 to -1 for the above code.

I am not quite getting how R places the values inside the interval in the plot that it gives. I mean, here shouldn't the frequency (y axis) be equal to 1 all the time, since there are no repetitions?

Also, I didn't quite get how the range works, is it upper bound inclusive / lower bound inclusive or..?? [,) or (,] or [,] or (,) ..?

Answer (score 3):

All your questions can be answered by reading the help file for `hist`, `help('hist')` or `?hist`

There are arguments `include.lowest` and `right` which both default to `TRUE`

Quoting from the help

> -*include.lowest*
>
> logical; if TRUE, an x[i] equal to the breaks value will be included in the first (or last, for right = FALSE) bar. This will be ignored (with a warning) unless breaks is a vector.
>
> -*right*
>
> logical; if TRUE, the histogram cells are right-closed (left open) intervals.